# Expanding tensor using native tensorflow ops

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a single dimensional data (floats) as shown below:

[-8., 18., 9., -3., 12., 11., -13., 38., ...]

I want to replace each negative element with an equivalent number of zeros.
My result would look something like this for the example above:

[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 18., 9., 0., 0., 0., 12., ...]

I am able to do this in Tensorflow by using tf.py_func(). 
But it turns out the graph is not serializable if I use that method.

Are there native tensorflow ops that can help me get the same result?

Comment: I assume `0` values should stay? Or should they be considered as "replace by zero `0`s" and therefore removed?

Comment: Zero values should stay yes! Sorry for not being clear on that one. But zeros would be a pretty rare in my data. I have not come across any so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a straightforward task! Here is a pure TensorFlow implementation:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Input vector
inp = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
# Find positive and negative indices
mask = inp < 0
num_inputs = tf.size(inp)
pos_idx, neg_idx = tf.dynamic_partition(tf.range(num_inputs), tf.cast(mask, tf.int32), 2)
# Negative values
negs = -tf.gather(inp, neg_idx)
total_neg = tf.reduce_sum(negs)
cum_neg = tf.cumsum(negs)
# Compute the final index of each positive element
pos_neg_idx = tf.cast(pos_idx[:, tf.newaxis] > neg_idx, inp.dtype)
neg_ref = tf.reduce_sum(pos_neg_idx, axis=1)
shifts = tf.gather(tf.concat([[0], cum_neg], axis=0), neg_ref) - neg_ref
final_pos_idx = pos_idx + shifts
# Compute the final size
final_size = num_inputs + total_neg - tf.size(negs)
# Make final vector by scattering positive values
result = tf.scatter_nd(final_pos_idx[:, tf.newaxis], tf.gather(inp, pos_idx), [final_size])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(result, feed_dict={inp: [-1, 1, -2, 2, 1, -3]}))
```

Output:

```
[0 1 0 0 2 1 0 0 0]
```

There is some "more than necessary" computational cost in this solution, namely the computation of final indices of positive elements through `pos_neg_idx`, which is O(*n*<sup>2</sup>), while it could be done iteratively in O(*n*). However, I cannot think of a way to replicate the loop iteratively, and a TensorFlow loop (using `tf.while_loop`) would be awkward and slow. In any case, unless you are using quite large vectors (with evenly distributed positive and negative values) it should not be a big issue.

Comment: Thank you! That's a nice solution. And regarding the index, I tested it for a large randomly allocated input value and yes it takes a longer time than I would like for it to run. But yeah even I wasn't very confident of a while loop solution when I was first thinking of things I can try.

Comment: @kvish I made a small change that makes is slightly faster (although the overall complexity is the same).

Comment: Thank you @jdehesa! I was trying some optimizations and pre-allocating a tensor and then using tf.dynamic_stitch to update it seems to also be slightly faster with respect to using scatter_nd. Reference: https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/432de370d9d0f3878ea754af39134b50

Comment: @kvish Nice, thanks for sharing that. It's interesting that `tf.dynamic_stitch` is faster than `tf.scatter_nd` when they do essentially the same here (I imagine it's because `tf.scatter_nd` can also work with multiple dimensions?...). Anyway glad you got to improve it.

Comment: Probably because you need a flat tensor to use dynamic_stitch maybe yes!